# How to select values from datatable based on another datatable using DataRow list

Tags: c#

I have 2 datatable

I want to filter result in DataTable dtPross (the Second) based on data in datatable dtSeats (the First)

I use this code:

```
DataTable dtSeats = new DataTable();
dtSeats = "select SitNum,Num from dbo.Table1"
SitNumList = (from row in dtSeats.AsEnumerable() 
             select Convert.ToInt32(row["SitNum"])).ToList();
```

When I use this code to filter the data based on Datarow list

```
DataTable dtPross = "select SitNum from dbo.Table2 where SitNum in (" + SitNumList.ToList() + ")";
```

I got this error

```
SitNum in (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32])
```

Did i miss something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you missed to convert `List<int>` to comma seperated elements string.

Try below code

```
//Below code will convert List<int> SitNumList = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3, 4} to string "1, 2, 3, 4"
string siteNums = string.Join(", ", SitNumList);
DataTable dtPross = "select SitNum from dbo.Table2 where SitNum in (" + siteNums  + ")";
```

Comment: Why `SitNumList.Select(x => x.ToString())`? Couldn't you just pass `SitNumList` because it's already IEnumerable?

Comment: @JohnyL, I updated my answer, I thought I need to convert integer to string first and then pass it to `string.Join()`, Thanks for correction

Comment: Not at all.  Now all is OK. 